# Desktop app installation folder change through Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I created a sample Codename One project in netbeans and generated a desktop build.while installing .exe its not giving me the provision to select specific location to install.

Once I got the exe from codename one dashboard,I installed the .exe and it got installed in default folder like c://user/AppData/...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA9nh.png)

Comment: So what is it that you want the community to help you with exactly?

Comment: I want the app to install in separate location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal we had when we created this was to make the installation minimal just like a mobile phone/tablet installer. The experience might be slightly different for the [ZuluFX version](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/zulu-desktop-builds.html) where we have more control over the result.

If not you can try the MSI build (not supported for Zulu) which might give you a better install experience.

Comment: Thank You @Shai. It worked for me and i checked in demo projects also.